# svg styles interfering with each other

Tags: css, svg

I have a bunch of logo's, generated with illustrator, that I would like to embed in my website directly. The svgs all have a `<style>` element where the styles are defined inside the svg element, something like this:

```
<svg>
  <style>
    .st1 { fill:#ff00ff; }
    .st2 { fill:#ff3421; }
    /* ... and so on */
  </style>
    <!-- svg paths and shapes -->
</svg>
```

The problem is that these styles interfer with each other. So if the last images defines `.st21 {fill:#555555}` this style is applied to all path with `class="st21"`, including paths from all previously loaded svg images.

In another thread somebody suggested to wrap my svg-xml with an `<object>` tag, that doesn't seem to work.

How can I make sure that inline SVG styles are not interfering with each other, without touching the actual SVG code?

here's a pen to illustrate the problem: https://codepen.io/pwkip/pen/RLPgpW

Comment: Embed them with `<img>` if possible. Also tell your graphic designer to set `CSS Properties` to `Presentation Attributes` in Illustrater when exporting the SVGs

Comment: @lumio thanks. Presentation Attributes worked, but it made the file size go from 10kB to 180kB, so I'm looking for a way to make styles stop interfering with each other. Wrapping with img instead of object doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The word "wrap" is not in my answer, you've imagined/added that yourself. object/iframe tags are for external content, they don't "wrap" anything.

Comment: What you could do is parse the style container and apply the styles manually

Comment: I've got a similar situation, but styles were messed up because of same ids. Had to change id in one of the svgs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a JavaScript solution. Although this might be a little overkill and slow if you use a lot of SVGs. But this works fine so far.

What I do is, I iterate over all SVGs and collect/parse their CSS styles. I collect all class names and properties and apply them manually onto the SVG elements.

```js
const svgCollection = document.querySelectorAll( 'svg' );

function parseStyles( styleTag ) {
  if ( !styleTag ) {
    return {};
  }
  
  const classCollection = {};
  
  const plain = styleTag.innerHTML;
  const regex = /\.([^\s{]+)[\s]*\{([\s\S]+?)\}/;
  const propertyRegex = /([\w\-]+)[\s]*:[\s]*([^;]+)/;
  const result = plain.match( new RegExp( regex, 'g' ) );
  if ( result ) {
    result.forEach( c => {
      const classResult = c.match( regex );
      const propertiesResult = classResult[ 2 ].match( new RegExp( propertyRegex, 'g' ) );
      const properties = propertiesResult.reduce( ( collection, item ) => {
        const p = item.match( propertyRegex );
        collection[ p[ 1 ] ] = p[ 2 ];
        return collection;
      }, {} );
      
      classCollection[ classResult[ 1 ] ] = properties;
    } );
    
    return classCollection;
  }
  
  return {};
}

function applyProperties( element, properties ) {
  if ( !properties ) {
    return;
  }
  
  Object.keys( properties ).forEach( key => {
    element.style[ key ] = properties[ key ];
  } );
}

function applyStyles( element, styles ) {
  const classNames = ( element.getAttribute( 'class' ) || '' ).split( ' ' );
  classNames.forEach( c => {
    applyProperties( element, styles[ c ] );
  } );
  element.setAttribute( 'class', '' );
}

for ( let i = 0; i < svgCollection.length; i += 1 ) {
  const svg = svgCollection[ i ];
  const styles = parseStyles( svg.querySelector( 'style' ) );
  const elements = svg.querySelectorAll( '[class]' );
  for ( let j = 0; j < elements.length; j += 1 ) {
    applyStyles( elements[ j ], styles );
  }
}
```

```html
<p>this shape should be blue:</p>
<svg height="210" width="210">
  <style>
    .st1 {
      fill:blue;
    }
  </style>
  <polygon points="100,10 40,198 190,78 10,78 160,198" class="st1"/>
</svg>
<p>this shape should be red:</p>
<svg height="210" width="210">
  <style>
    .st1 {
      fill:red;
    }
  </style>
  <ellipse cx="105" cy="80" rx="100" ry="50" class="st1" />
</svg>
```

Even though this works great, I wouldn't suggest it (as mentioned in the comments at your question). Better to set `CSS Properties` to `Presentation Attributes` in Illustrater

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest to export svg with appropriate CSS properties in the first place. 
During export from Illustrator choose :`style attributes` it would be something like this in svg:

`<path style="fill: red"></path>`

It could increase your file size but it definitely do the job. I found a nice explanation [here](http://cobwwweb.com/inline-style-attributes-svg-elements)

Comment: i think I will make sure the designers will do this in the future. This is probably the most useful answer I got, but it involves changing the svg code, so can't accept it. +1 though ;)